# AD FS 2.0 install on Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, adfs

I am attempting to install AD FS 2.0 on a 64-bit Server 2008 R2.
I've downloaded it from the [MS Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10909), which states that Server 2008 R2 is one of the supported operating systems.

When I run the executable that's downloaded, I get and error message stating:

> This AD FS 2.0 installtion requires the Windows Server 2008 SP2
>   operating system.

I found an [MS page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd807096(WS.10).aspx) about the requirements of installing on Server 2008 and 2008 R2.
Here are some requirements that I've installed or are already installed:

- Windows Identity Foundation (WIF):  Installed from the [MS Download
  Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17331)
- IIS 7: 7.5 is installed since it's a Server 2008 R2 machine.
- Windows Hotfix (KB981002): I followed the link that states I can
  download the hot fixes from here, but I get the message that the
  update is not applicable to my computer.
- .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1:  I have .Net 3.5.1 and 4.5.1 installed.

Is there something else that I need to install before the AD FS executable will work?

Any leads are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three different downloads on that page, did you select the one for 2008 R2 or 2008 SP2?  They are different products.